# How to receive Json parameters from post request as JObject in ASP.NET Core 8.0 controller?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-8.0

I have an application perfectly functioning, built in Angular 13 and .NET Core 2.1. Now I am upgrading it to .NET 8.0. I have successfully upgraded all other features, but I'm stuck at receiving the parameters as JObject.

In the old version, I pass the parameters from frontend in JSON like this:

```
"{ "query": "dotNet" }"
```

And the structure of backend controller action is as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataAsync([FromBody] JObject jSearchItems)
{
     try
     {
         dynamic SearchItems = jSearchItems;
         string query = SearchItems.query;

         ServiceResponse response = await _Service.GetDataAsync(query);

         return StatusCode((int)(response.IsValid ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest), response);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Note that the type of function parameter is `JObject`.

In .NET core 2.1, this was working correctly, but when I upgraded it to .NET 8.0, the data is received as `null` in the controller method.

If I create a new model for parameters as follows:

```
class SearchItem
{
    public string query { get; set; }
}
```

and change the type of parameters from `JObject` to `SearchItem`, then the data is received correctly.

But I do not want to create hundreds of classes because there are a lot of API methods in this application.

So how can I receive JSON parameters from post request as `JObject` in ASP.NET Core 8.0 controllers?

Comment: I am assumig `JObject` comes from `Newtonsoft.Json`? `System.Text.Json`, which is the default JSON serializer for .NET 8 projects does not have `JObject`. Did you configure Newtonsoft.Json to be the (de-)serializer to use?

Comment: @Mushroomator In this case what will be the alternative of `JObject` in `System.Text.Json` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

first install nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
and then in program.cs add:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: so this will switch default JSON serializer from `System.Text.Json` to `Newtonsoft.Json`. I am curious if there are any disadvantages of doing that?

Comment: Considering that you have a lot of APIs, in my opinion, this is the least expensive solution.
But maybe not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

From ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later versions, the default JSON serializer used is `System.Text.Json`, which may behave differently compared to the `Newtonsoft.Json` library used in earlier versions. In your case, when receiving the JSON payload as `JObject`,`System.Text.Json` may not automatically bind the request body to a `JObject` object as `Newtonsoft.Json` did.

However, you can still achieve similar behavior by reading the request body as a string and then manually parsing it into a `JObject`. Here's how you can do it:

Ex:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Read the request body as a string
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            
            JObject jSearchItems = JObject.Parse(requestBody);
            
            string query = (string)jSearchItems["query"];

            // ServiceResponse response = await _Service.GetDataAsync(query);

            return Ok(new { query }); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This approach allows you to receive `JSON` parameters as `JObject` in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later versions without explicitly defining a model class for each API endpoint.